# Variable scope in WordPress functions.php

Tags: functions

The `functions.php` file for a theme contains functions, called by hooks, that could be called from multiple WordPress pages. The `wp` hook, for example, seems to be on every page. You can decide in each function with `is_page()` which page is calling and whether or not you want to execute the function for that page.

What is the scope of variables you declare at the top of `functions.php`, outside of any of the individual functions? Can that variable be read by any page with a hook to the function? Can one page set the variable and another page read it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*What is the scope of variables you declare at the top of functions.php, outside of any of the individual functions?*

This is a general PHP question...

> Variables inside a function are only available inside that function.
>   Variables outside of functions are available anywhere outside of
>   functions, but not inside any function. This means there's one special
>   scope in PHP: the global scope. Any variable declared outside of any
>   function is within this global scope. ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and))

*Can that variable be read by any page with a hook to the function?*

If the variable is declared as global, then yes.

*Can one page set the variable and another page read it?*

No, only one page is loaded per a loop. And each time you load a page the variable is "forgotten" unless you store it someplace. If you want to set variables, you'll need to use a WP function such as [`update_option()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) and [`get_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option). This stores the variable in the database.